# How can I use all four D-Pad secondary weapon slots in Darksiders?

Tags: darksiders

I am currently playing Darksiders and the down slot in the D-Pad has somehow been assigned to the gauntlet.  I want to assign the horn to the down slot in the D-pad but when I try to do it, the slot is simply blocked.  I can't 'move' the item to the slot below, only to the top three slots shown.
[image]

This is what it looks like while playing.  The gauntlet has fixed itself in the bottom slot and I cannot remove it.

[image]

Is there a way to reset or clear these assignments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to reassign the bottom slot.
This slot will either hold the Gauntlet or the Scythe.
The bottom slot will hold what is currently not equipped.